# How do I include the root in my json responses when using Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongoid

Seems pretty easy with ActiveRecord:

```
config.active_record.include_root_in_json = true
```

But I can't find the proper Mongoid documentation

Answer (score 4):

here are the docs your looking for:

http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html

according to docs in config/mongoid.yml, you simply need to set:

`include_root_in_json: true`

cheers

Answer (score 0):

in Rails 4 with jbuilder using include_root_in_json setting in mongoid.yml did not add the wrapper. I updated my jbuilder templates like this:

```
# wrap scaffolded template with set!
# people/index.json

json.set! :people do
  json.array!(@people) do |p|
    json.extract! p, :name, :age
  end
end #=> returns {"people" : [ "name" : "Jane", "age" : 30 ] }
```